# Python: Plotting comma separated values within two different columns of a single row (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, list, matplotlib, seaborn

Say I have a dataframe structured like so:

```
Name        x        y
Joe       0,1,5    0,3,8
Sue       0,2,8    1,9,5
...
Harold    0,5,6    0,7,2
```

I'd like to plot the values in the x and y axis on a line plot based on row. In reality, there are many x and y values, but there is always one x value for every y value in these columns. The name of the plot would be the value in "name".

I've tried to do this by first converting x and y to lists in their own separate columns like so:

```
df['xval'] = df.['x'].str.split(',')
df['yval'] = df.['y'].str.split(',')
```

And then passing them to seaborn:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x=df['xval'], y=df['yval'], data=df)
```

However, this does not work because 1) I recieve an error, which I *presume* is due to attempting to pass a list from a dataframe, claiming:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

And 2) I cannot specify the value for df['name'] for the specific line plot. What's the best way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: What do you expect `sns.lineplot` to produce, given that each value of `xval` and `yval` is a list? What is your desired output?

Comment: @larsks My desired output is to have a lineplot for each row where the name of the plot is the value for the name column, the x axis are the values from the list of the x column and the y axis are the values from the list of the y column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['joe', 'sue', 'mike'],
    'x': ['0,1,5', '0,2,8', '0,4'],
    'y': ['0,3,8', '1,9,5', '1,6']
})
```

We should convert `df` into a useable format for plotting. This makes all plotting eaiser. We can take advantage of the fact that `x` and `y` have a 1-to-1 relationship. Notice I've added a third name with a 2 xy value as opposed to 3 to show this method will work for varied amounts of x and y per name as long as each row has equal numbers of x and y values.

---

Creating the `plot_df`:

```
# Grab Name Column to Start Plot DF with
plot_df = df.loc[:, ['name']]
# Split X column
plot_df['x'] = df['x'].str.split(',')
# Explode X into Rows
plot_df = plot_df.explode('x').reset_index(drop=True)
# Split and Series Explode y in one step
# This works IF AND ONLY IF a 1-to-1 relationship for x and y
plot_df['y'] = df['y'].str.split(',').explode().reset_index(drop=True)
# These need to be numeric to plot correctly
plot_df.loc[:, ['x', 'y']] = plot_df.loc[:, ['x', 'y']].astype(int)
```

`plot_df`:

```
   name  x  y
0   joe  0  0
1   joe  1  3
2   joe  5  8
3   sue  0  1
4   sue  2  9
5   sue  8  5
6  mike  0  1
7  mike  4  6
```

References to the methods used in creating `plot_df`:

1. [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to subset the dataframe
2. [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the comma separated values into a list
3. [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to upscale the DataFrame based on the iterable in `x`
4. [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to make index unique again after exploding
5. [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to upscale the lists in the Series `y`.
6. [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to make index unique again after exploding
7. [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) since the values are initially strings just splitting and exploding is not enough. Will need to convert to a numeric type for them to plot correctly

---

Plotting (Option 1)

```
# Plot with hue set to name.
sns.lineplot(data=plot_df, x='x', y='y', hue='name')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1]

References for plotting separate lines:

1. [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) to plot. Note the `hue` argument to create separate lines based on `name`.
2. [`pyplot.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) to display.

---

Plotting (Option 2.a) Subplots:

```
sns.relplot(data=plot_df, x='x', y='y', col='name', kind='line')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2.a relplot (FacetGrid)]

Plotting (Option 2.b) Subplots:

```
# Use Grouper From plot_df
grouper = plot_df.groupby('name')

# Create Subplots based on the number of groups (ngroups)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=grouper.ngroups)

# Iterate over axes and groups
for ax, (grp_name, grp) in zip(axes, grouper):
    # Plot from each grp DataFrame on ax from axes
    sns.lineplot(data=grp, x='x', y='y', ax=ax, label=grp_name)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2.b subplots (matplotlib)]

References for plotting subplots:

2.a

1. [`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) the `row` or `col` parameter can be used to create subplots in a similar way to how `hue` creates multiple lines. This will return a [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) so post processing will be different than `lineplot` which returns [matplotlib.axes.Axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html)

2.b

1. [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) to create iterable that can be used to plot subplots.
2. [`pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to create subplots to plot on.
3. [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to count number of groups.
4. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over axes and groups simultaneously.
5. [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) to plot. Note `label` is needed to have legends. `grp_name` contains the current key that is common in the current `grp` DataFrame.
6. [`pyplot.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) to display.

---

Plotting option 3 (separate plots):

```
# Plot from each grp DataFrame in it's own plot
for grp_name, grp in plot_df.groupby('name'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.lineplot(data=grp, x='x', y='y', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(grp_name)
    fig.show()
```

| joe plot | mike plot | sue plot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: joe plot] | [image: mike plot] | [image: sue plot] |

References for plotting separate plots:

1. [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) to create iterable that can be used to plot each name separately.
2. [`pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to create separate plot to plot on.
3. [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) to plot. Note `label` is needed to have legends. `grp_name` contains the current key that is common in the current `grp` DataFrame.
4. [`pyplot.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) to display.

Comment: Fantastic answer, breaking everything down was extremely helpful.  One of my issues was trying to determining a more useful way to organize the data in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice, but I would suggest using `relplot(..., col='name')` for subplots, since you already have long-form data.

Comment: Thank you @mwaskom updated my answer. `relplot` is a great addition.

Comment: @HenryEcker Perhaps unrelated to the original question, but I'm still having trouble with converting from string values to ints. Checking the datatype before `plot_df.loc[:, ['x', 'y']] = plot_df.loc[:, ['x', 'y']].astype(int)` shows that 'x' and 'y' are objects and afterwards they are not converted (still objects).

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by creating another dataframe and changing `plot_df.loc[:, ['x', 'y']] ... .astype(int)`  to `ndf.loc[:, ['x', 'y']] ... .astype(int)`  Any suggestions for more elegant ways of doing this would be appreciated though.

Comment: I'm really not sure... `astype` does not fail silently. If it had trouble converting anything it should raise an error.

Comment: Wasn't looking for an answer to any question I had, but I'm upvoting for the sheer effort in this answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood this is what you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['joe', 'sue']
df['x'] = ['0,1,5', '0,2,8']
df['y'] = ['0,3,8', '1,9,5']
df['newx'] = df['x'].str.split(',')
df['newy'] = df['y'].str.split(',')
for i in range(len(df)):
    sns.lineplot(x=df.loc[i, 'newx'], y=df.loc[i, 'newy'])
plt.legend(df['name'])
```